# How to swap the words in the list.

Tags: java

How can reprint this string

```
List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();

        abc.add("D. Bwer");
        abc.add("Z. abc");
        abc.add("X. RDS");


Output : Bwer, D. 
         abc, Z.
         RDS, X.
```

tried swapping the indexes but didnt work

Comment: Where is your swapping code?

Comment: Will it always be `.`? if Ya you can split and rebuild each item. Is the length always the same? you can split by position

Comment: show us what u have done till now ??

Comment: Do you have to store both the parts of the string in that way? I would split it into two parts, store them in an object and add the object to the list. Having done that, doing things such as swapping would be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
    List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();
    abc.add("D. Bwer");
    abc.add("Z. abc");
    abc.add("X. RDS");
    for(String i:abc){
        String[] arr=i.split(" ");
        System.out.println(arr[1]+", "+arr[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();

    abc.add("D. Bwer");
    abc.add("Z. abc");
    abc.add("X. RDS");

      List<String> string1= new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String str1: abc){
            String new1= str1.split("\\s+")[0]; 
            String new2= str1.split("\\s+")[1]; 
            String temp = new2+","+ new1;

            string1.add(temp );
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go by substring

First solution if space location varies.

Second solution if you know that space will always be present at third location.

```
 List<String> abc = new ArrayList<String>();

    abc.add("D. Bwer");
    abc.add("Z. abc");
    abc.add("X. RDS");

    for(String dummy:abc){
         System.out.println((dummy.substring(dummy.indexOf(" ")+1))+",      
         "+dummy.substring(0, dummy.indexOf(" ")));  //1

        System.out.println(dummy.substring(3)+", "+dummy.substring(0,3)); //2
    }
```

Comment: Surnames and first names could be longer than 3 characters. Those were examples.

Comment: agreed , that's why i put the condition for 2nd solution.

Answer (score -1):

To swap elements of Java ArrayList use,
static void swap(List list, int firstElement, int secondElement)
method of Collections class. Where firstElement is the index of first
element to be swapped and secondElement is the index of the second element
to be swapped.

If the specified positions are equal, list remains unchanged.

Please note that, this method can throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if
any of the index values is not in range.

```
Collections.swap(arrayList,0,4);
```

Comment: That is not the question. OP wants to swap words in the string.(Did not downvote though)